# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xxx.xxx.xxx.Xxx$Xxx (Dalvik only)

Tags: android, android-multidex

I wrote a library  that has an implementation of Shared Preferences where it reduces the reported ANR's, which was working until today, one application started to throw `NoClassDefFoundError`. It doesn't happen on any other apps where it has the library, and it happens on **debug** build only, it doesn't happen on release build. But it's still important because that means I will eventually face this issue in the future.

Note that the app was using multidex for a year now, with proper implementation, which means `attachBaseContext` is overridden, `multiDexEnabled` is already true etc...

I should also mention that the `getSharedPreferences` method is overridden in the application class.

```
public class AppClass extends MultiDexApplication
{
    // onCreate and rest of the code    

    // Return a special SharedPreferences instance
    // to apply changes properly.
    @Override
    public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)
    {
        return SharedPreferencesWrapper.getInstance(name, super.getSharedPreferences(name, mode));
    }
}
```

The APK is big, it has 4 `classes.dex` files and I've noticed, the `SharedPreferences` class that tries to load the `SharedPreferences.Editor` instance is located in `classes.dex` while the class that implements the editor is in `classes2.dex`. I believe this is the reason that the program fails with an exception like this:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: firebase-iid-executor
    Process: com.test.app, PID: 4226
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mylibrary.SharedPreferencesWrapper$SharedPreferencesEditor
        at com.mylibrary.SharedPreferencesWrapper.edit(SharedPreferencesWrapper.java:311)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzaz.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.1:53)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zzl(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.1:70)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.1:159)
        at com.google.firebase.iid.zzk.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.2.1)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzg.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.0.2:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.2.1:6)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

I can also see dalvik is complaining about not finding the class as well:

> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.mylibrary.SharedPreferencesWrapper$SharedPreferencesEditor', referenced from method com.mylibrary.SharedPreferencesWrapper.edit

This is where it fails:

```
public class SharedPreferencesWrapper implements SharedPreferences
{
    // rest of the methods

    @Override
    public Editor edit()
    {
        // This is where it fails
        return new SharedPreferencesEditor();
    }

    // The wrapper editor class that performs modifying the map
    // and writes to files etc...
    // This class is not in the same .dex file as the parent class.
    // Notice that the class isn't "static", but making it static
    // and passing a reference doesn't help either.
    public class SharedPreferencesEditor implements SharedPreferences.Editor
    {
         // some class variables, no static block defined,
         // no exceptions are thrown in the constructor.
         // It doesn't even reach the constructor.
    }
}
```

In this code block, after building the APK file, I can see `SharedPreferencesWrapper` is in `classes.dex` and `SharedPreferencesWrapper$SharedPreferencesEditor` is in `classes2.dex`. I assume it cannot find the class because it's in a different .dex file, but I don't know how can I put it in the same dex file either.

I also noticed that the `<clinit>` exists for `SharedPreferencesWrapper` on APK analyzer, but not for `SharedPreferencesWrapper$SharedPreferencesEditor`. **This looks like important to me**, but I'm not sure how to solve it.

**Edit**: `<clinit>` started to appear after adding a static variable to the class. Apparently it relates to that because there are multiple classes that doesn't have the `<clinit>` definition but works perfectly anyway. However, the exception still persists.

What I've tried so far:

1. Moving the editor class into its own file and passing the instance of shared preferences wrapper itself (because it is necessary),
2. Making the editor class static and passing the reference of the object,
3. Using old gradle version and old multi-dex version (currently I'm using 2.0.1),
4. Cleaning the project, rebuilding the project, removing build folders, removing caches, invalidate cache & restart option, re-importing the project from git etc... all that stuff.

Is there a solution to this? I have no idea what to do. Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.